# Google Chart - Timelines: Scaling Axis

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm trying to create a chart using Google's Timeline that shows activity over the last 7 days, and I'm running into problems with scaling the x-axis.

The chart is always trying to auto-scale to the data, which ruins the consistency I'd like to incorporate. I want the right side of the graph to be today's date, and the left side to be seven days before today's date.

I can't seem to find anything for fixing the x-axis in the documentation for [Timelines](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline) or even [Visualization](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Configuration_Options) in general, but I have to believe a charting library has the ability to configure its own axes. Does anyone have a solution that works?

A possible workaround I have is creating two data points -- one for today and one for today-7 -- and add them to the graph. This fixes the scaling problem, but now my graph has two arbitrary data points on it. (I know it's technically a separate question, but if anyone knows how to hide these two data points while still maintaining the fixed axis scale that'd be a win!)

Here's what my graph looks like using just the raw data (notice the axis -- I would like this to be last 7 days):[image: axis auto-scaled]

And here's what it looks like with my two 'faked' data points:[image: axis fixed-scaled, but two bad data points]

EDIT: I have tried using the viewWindow.max and viewWindow.min properties, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can white out the two dummy points by using options like:

```
  var options = {
    colors: ['#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#c69c6e'],
  };
```